# "belongs to" and "has many" through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, model-associations

Here is what I have and want to achieve:

I have 2 models `Category` and `Collection`

I want this association:

`Category` belongs to `Collection`

`Collection` has many `Category`

BUT I need this association only for a few records. Like 100.
So I don't see any reason to create column with reference for the rest 100 000 records.

I tried this with no luck:

```
class Category
  has_many :category_collection

  # This is not a valid option
  belongs_to :collection, through: :category_collection

  # And this will throw
  has_one :collection, through: :category_collection

  # ActiveRecord::HasOneThroughCantAssociateThroughCollection: Cannot have
  # a has_one :through association 'Category#collection'
  # where the :through association 'Category#category_collection' is
  # a collection. Specify a has_one or belongs_to association 
  # in the :through option instead.
end

class Collection
  has_many :category_collection
  has_many :categories, through: :category_collection
end

class CategoryCollection
  self.table_name = 'categories_collections'
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :collection
end
```

Or maybe whole idea is wrong and I should stick with useless column?

Comment: I think all you need to do is ->`Collecion has many :categories` & `Category belongs_to :collection`

Comment: @nik Yes, in this situation I'll get useless column for the rest 99k records. Read question one more time please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Category` belongs to `Collection` means `Category` model has a reference to `Collection` (`collection_id` field).  So you cannot do it without having 99k useless records.

But it's possible to define `has_one` association instead.

```
class Category
  has_one :category_collection 
  has_one :collection, through: :category_collection
end
```

Comment: What will he achieve by doing  `has_one` ? Could you please explain

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is a bit dirty I would say, but you could probably set it up like this. If this is totally crazy please let me know.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :category_collection
  has_one :collection, through: :category_collection
end

class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_collections
  has_many :categories, through: :category_collections
end

class CategoryCollection < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'categories_collections'
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :collection

  validate :only_one_category

  def only_one_category
    if CategoryCollection.all.pluck(:category_id).include?(category.id)
      errors.add(:category, "can only have one collection")
    end
  end
end
```

The validation will make sure that you cannot add multiple collections to one category.